# UITableView content offset -64pt issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am debugging table view and in my `-viewDidLoad` method I have:

```
<UITableView: 0x7b394600; frame = (0 0; 1024 768); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7983d2f0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x79836ca0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
```

but when I check the frame and content offset in `-viewDidAppear` method:

```
<UITableView: 0x7ab79c00; frame = (0 0; 1024 768); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7998f700>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7998f560>; contentOffset: {0, -64}>
```

I don't know how table get -64 for its offset.

There is just sequence of methods view did load and then view did appear but content offset magically changed for me.

What can be a reason?

This is my viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _theTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];

    _theTableView.dataSource = self;
    _theTableView.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:_theTableView];

    _theTableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    self.title = @"File Manager";
}
```

I have navigation bar, but weird that I see my table as it should be without shifting. So looks perfect I see top cell and when I scroll to the bottom I see last cell. Even indicator says to me that content offset is 0. If I force set content offset {0, 0} then seems like first cell goes under navigation bar and vertical indicator starts not from the top but with some padding about 64 pt, but it's strange.

I suppose this is because of status bar and navigation bar. But if hardcoded create my offset and frame, it does not help me. Seems like system does it form me automatically =)

Comment: are you using Autolayout ? if yes then you can add constraint of TopSpacetoSuperview then Check

Comment: @parvind I've used layouts as well but seems like still has those -64 pt by y. in fact i just see it in log, visually everything looks good. but when i try to scroll i need to compare my content offset when it's near to 0, but the initial point of content offset -64 and then i should compare my things based on -64 pt instead of 0

Comment: Just a note: the two logs at the top of this post are *two different `UITableView`s* – the addresses are different!

Comment: @RileyAvron, omg, yep you are right ) I just test it few times and seems copied previous one. But in any case for the same instance I have different offsets.

Answer (score 5):

This is the default behaviour, look into `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets`:

> Default value is YES, which allows the view controller to adjust its
>   scroll view insets in response to the screen areas consumed by the
>   status bar, navigation bar, and toolbar or tab bar. Set to NO if you
>   want to manage scroll view inset adjustments yourself, such as when
>   there is more than one scroll view in the view hierarchy.

…and other related things in [iOS 7 UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html).